# storing variables in dictionary and descending order sorting

Tags: python, dictionary

In my code how can i store and sort in descendinng order in a dictionary.

I wanted to store `Item` as key, and `Mutual_information` as value and store them in a descending order based on the `Mutual_information` numerical value, in a dictionary.

My coding, which contains variables `item` and `Mutual_information`:

```
for item in lines:
    specificy = c[item]
    try:
        MI1= specificy/float(specificx)
        MI2= MI1*specificx
        M13= specificx*specificx
        Mutual_Information = MI1* math.log(MI1/float(MI2))
        print item, Mutual_Information #to be stored in descendin
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "divide by zero"
```

Comment: dicts have no order, you will need a `collections.OrderedDict` if you want  any order, you will need to sort the data first then create an OrderedDict

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment dicts are unordered so this will get all the items in a list then sort in reverse order and create an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from those sorted elements:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

# store all key,value pairings to sort later
items = []
for item in lines:
    specificy = c[item]
    try:
        MI1= specificy/float(specificx)
        MI2= MI1*specificx
        M13= specificx*specificx
        Mutual_Information = MI1* math.log(MI1/float(MI2))
        # add tuple of key/value to items
        items.append((item,Mutual_Information))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "divide by zero"

# create OrderedDict from sorted items, sorting by the second element
d = OrderedDict(sorted(items,key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
```

An example using a list of tuples:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items = [(1, 3), (4, 7), (2, 4), (6, 10)]
from operator import itemgetter

d = OrderedDict(sorted(items, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
print(d)
OrderedDict([(6, 10), (4, 7), (2, 4), (1, 3)])
```